# interface implementation and instantiation

Tags: java

Suppose interface `Inty` defines five methods.

Suppose class `Classy` declares that it implements `Inty` but does not provide implementations for any of the five interface methods.

Which is/are true?

- A. The class will not compile.
- B. The class will compile if it is declared public.
- C. The class will compile if it is declared abstract.
- D. The class may not be instantiated.

I think answer should be C only because an abstract class can not be instantiated in any way(letting apart the anonymous subclass).

Please let me know if I am right or wrong.

Comment: Clearly a homework drop-off...

Answer (score 0):

```
The class will not compile
```

you have to overrider all methods in interface in your class since `Classy` is normal `Java` class. If it is abstract that will compile.

Then both A and C correct.

Comment: Why Classy is normal Java class?

Comment: @user3301492 I want to say it didn't tell that is abstract.

Comment: And what is in option C? "The class will compile if it is declared abstract".

Comment: @user3301492 If so that is also true.

Answer (score 0):

> If the class is not abstract, then it won't compile. If it is
>   abstract, then it will compile but needs its concrete child to
>   implement the methods. So options A and C are correct.

Comment: So D is correct? Can you instantiate a class that "implements Inty but does not provide implementations for any of the five interface methods"?